# Error in sum(count) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Tags: r, dplyr, closures, frequency

I have an order table that looks like this:

```
country_code other_info order_status
FR           1523       okay
FR           5151       not_okay
FR           41511      not_okay
IE           5151       okay
```

Both columns are of class character but even when transforming them into factors I got the same issue.

I just want to have the proportions of order_status grouped by country_code.

After running the following code I've got this error and I really cannot figure out what it means:

```
'Error in sum(count) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
```

```
library(dplyr)
orders %>%
  group_by(country_code) %>%
  mutate(countT= sum(count)) %>%
  group_by(order_status, add=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(per=paste0(round(100*count/countT,2),'%'))
```

What I want is this:

```
country_code order_status per
FR           okay         33%
FR           not_okay     66%
IE           okay         100%
```

Thank you very much for your help, I'm sure it's something not complicated.

Comment: There is no `count` column showed in the data. Perhaps you meant `countT = n())`

Comment: ... and therefore you get the error as R trys to `sum(dplyr::count())`.

Comment: Oh yeah... But when I tried n() earlier it said '`n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP's dataset, there is no 'count' column.  If we need to create a column of frequency, then either use `n()` in `mutate` after grouping by 'country_code' or directly `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
order %>%
     add_count(country_code) %>% # create a column with name 'n'
     group_by(country_code, order_status) %>% # grouped by two columns
     mutate(per = str_c(round(100 * n()/n, 2), '%')) # do the rest of computation
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   country_code, order_status [3]
#  country_code order_status     n per  
#  <chr>        <chr>        <int> <chr>
#1 FR           okay             2 50%  
#2 FR           not_okay         2 50%  
#3 IE           okay             1 100%
```

Or if we need a single row, use `summarise`

```
order %>%
     add_count(country_code) %>% # create a column with name 'n'
     group_by(country_code, order_status) %>% # grouped by two columns
     summarise(per = str_c(round(100 * n()/first(n), 2), '%'))
```

If we want to get summarised output, change the `mutate` to `summarise`

#### data

```
order <- structure(list(country_code = c("FR", "FR", "IE"), order_status = c("okay", 
"not_okay", "okay")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: With this I got an error for  saying there is no method for 'group_by_' that is applicable for an object of class 'function'

Comment: @Unidi what is the version of dplyr you have.

Comment: ‘dplyr’ version 1.0.0

Comment: @Unidi can you restart on a fresh R session with dplyr only loaded.  I updated the output and the data used

Comment: Now it works! But the thing is that I have actually other columns in my dataset and I just want to show the country code and the order status, nothing else, because to have the other columns creates duplicates 'per' values

Comment: @Unidi Then change `mutate` to `transmute` or `summarise` instead of `mutate`

Comment: Actually I've looked in detail into the results and it turns out that there are still some duplicated rows, don't really know why

Comment: @Unidi Can you update your post with the dput of a small example that shows this issue along with expected output.   If you do `summarise`, it will return only a single row per group though

Comment: @Unidi I think i understand why you are getting that.  In the dplyr 1.0.0, `summarise` can return more than one row per group.  Can you try `summarise(per = str_c(round(100 * n()/first(n), 2), '%'))` with `first`

Comment: That's it! Will reupdate the post and close this! Thanks a lot